# latexdiff does not diff enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate, latexdiff

I'm using latexdiff to produce a diff between the following two latex files.

Original:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{First item}
\item{Second item}
\item{Third item}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Revised:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{1st item}
\item{2nd item}
\item{3rd item}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it fails to produce a diff for the items in the diff file.

From the output of `latexdiff --show-config`:

```
ITEMCMD=item
LISTENV=(?:(?:itemize)|(?:description)|(?:enumerate))
```

it seems that the tool is aware of the `enumerate` environment and the `list` command.

Is diffing the `enumerate` environment a feature which latexdiff supports at all? Is this a bug? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you mean, `latexdiff` produces a diff file, but the diff file does not highlight the diffs inside enumerate, as you expected. Unrelated: You don't need parentheses here: `\item foo`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I corrected the wording. And yes, the parentheses seem to be causing the issue. When not using parentheses it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is a bug as reported in:
https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/issues/241

A workaround is to not use parentheses around each item. Then this works as expected.